# How to render output of user control to a string from a background job

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I'm trying to get the output from a user control into a string in order to send it through an email. It works if I call it from an ASP.Net page, but doesn't work when calling from a background job through HangFire. Here is the function being called:

```
public static string EmailReport(string strControl)
{            
    UserControl userControl = (UserControl)((Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler).LoadControl(strControl);            
    string smtpBody = userControl.RenderHtml().ToString();
}

public static class UserControlExtensions
{
    public static string RenderHtml(this UserControl control)       
    {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var page = new Page();
            page.Controls.Add(control);
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, sw, false);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

If I call `EmailReport` from the code behind of an .aspx page, it works fine. However, when calling it from a background job through hangfire/startup.cs, I get

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

on this line:

```
UserControl userControl = (UserControl)((Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler).LoadControl(strControl);
```

Is there any way to make this work or is there a different/better approach to getting the output of a specified page and sending it an email?

Comment: Usercontrol  will be null while calling from background job

Answer (score 0):

I did similar thing and it does work. I got a schedule task running on background to generate some client report weekly, I need to populate the html string then convert it into pdf file. Below is the code to use custom user control to generate html from my project

```
        var p = new Page();
        var control = (ClientReportPdfControl)p.LoadControl("~/mycontrolpath.ascx");

        control.ClientReportMeta = ClientReportMeta;//my user control custom property
        control.Report = CustomerReport;//my user control custom propert
        control.SetupControls();// my user control custom method, setup control e.g. repeater databind etc
        p.Controls.Add(control);
        StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        TextWriter myTextWriter = new StringWriter(myStringBuilder);
        HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myTextWriter);
        if (control != null && myWriter != null)
            control.RenderControl(myWriter);
        string html = myTextWriter.ToString();
```

In order to render the user control, it does require something in a normal a webpage (cannot remember what it is as it is been quite a while), your error my because you simply cast your hanlder into a page so it doesnt have that thing. Otherwise, you can have something similar to my code to setup your control to make sure the control setup properly

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a page that would load a specified control and email it. I call that page from HangFire using Webclient. Ugly workaround, but it works.